# Bulk Update Shopify tracking codes by rest API in Python

Tags: python-3.x, post, python-requests, shopify

I have referred to [Create a new fulfillment](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-04/resources/fulfillment#post-orders-order-id-fulfillments) Shopify dev documentation, but this will only gave me `<Response [400]>`

And I tried this one [Creats a fulfillment for one or many fulfillment orders](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-04/resources/fulfillment#post-fulfillments).
After sending the request, I got`<Response [201]>`, but the order shows **in progress** instead of **fulfilled**. Also the tracking code and the tracking company don't appear in the shop.

The following are the codes I was using. How can I update the tracking code and company.

#### Python Environment

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import requests 
import json
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict
headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
```

#### API authentication

```
# add parameter to headers
access_token = f'{token}'
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
headers["X-Shopify-Access-Token"] = f"{access_token}"
```

#### post body for tracking code/company/url information

```
data = {}
data['fulfillment'] = {}
data['fulfillment']['tracking_info'] = {}
data['fulfillment']['location_id'] = f'{location_id}'  # location id
data['fulfillment']['notify_customer'] = False
data['fulfillment']['status'] = 'success'

data['fulfillment']['tracking_info']['tracking_number'] = f'{trackingCode}'
data['fulfillment']['tracking_info']['company'] = 'DHL Express'
data['fulfillment']['tracking_info']['tracking_urls'] = f'https://www.dhl.com/us-en/home/tracking/tracking-express.html?submit=1&tracking-id={trackingCode}'
```

#### Send the post request

```
createFulfillment_url = f'{shop_url}/admin/api/2022-04/orders/{orderID}/fulfillments.json'
request.post(createFulfillment_url, headers = headers, json = data)
```

`<Response [201]>` but the tracking code and the company doesn't show

Comment: Have you tried using the Shopify python library?

Comment: I have tried, but the authentication is fairly complicated, and it couldn’t let me authenticated…

Comment: To authenticate you need to setup the session `shopify.Session.setup(api_key=env.client_id, secret=env.client_secret)` and use your access token `session = shopify.Session(env.store, version=api_version, token=env.access_token)` or your password `session = shopify.Session(env.store, api_version, env.password)` then you need activate the session `shopify.ShopifyResource.activate_session(session)` and that's it

Comment: Could I ask what's env.store? Is that the url of shopify?

Comment: Yes `https://yourstore.myshopify.com`